# Magento PayPal Checkout Flow - user has to login twice?

Tags: magento, paypal

we are working on optimisation for our Magento site. Here is the flow we found and not sure whether it could be improved.

When user clicks the PayPal checkout button, it is moved to Paypal login page. After login page, it shows the checkout page where user has to input password again. Is it normal? Can we skip the previous login page since user login twice during the checkout flow?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using express checkout? Have you tried to change "Skip Order Review Step" to yes?